# Questions about Lowey length

Tags: rt.representation-theory, modules

Let $\Lambda$ be an artin algebra.

1. If $M$ is a finitely generated $\Lambda$-module with Loewy length 2 and finite projective dimension. How to get the exact sequence  $$0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow P/rad^2P \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$$
   where $P$ is the projective cover of  $M$ and $A$ is semisimple?(I just know that $P/radP \cong M/radM$)
2. Suppose that $(rad \Lambda)^3=0$, for any $\Lambda$-module $M$, $\Omega M$ is the first syzygy of $M$. Then how to get $\Omega M$  has Loewy length at most 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have the projective cover $f:P \rightarrow M$ and since $M$ has Loewy length 2, rad^2(P) is in the kernel of f. Now the kernel A is a submodule of rad(P)/rad^2(P), which is semisimple.
2. Use the $\Omega(M)$ is always a submodule of the radical of a projective module (property of minimal projective cover).

Comment: Why the kernel $A$ is a submodule of $rad(P)/rad^2(P)$?

Comment: In general the kernel of a projective cover is contained in the radical of the projective module. it doesnt matter now that you factor out rad^2.